# Django-filebrowser incorrect image url

Tags: python, django, django-filebrowser

I'm using FileBrowser for upload image files. In my settings.py I set

```
from filebrowser.sites import site
site.storage.location =  SITE_ROOT + "/static/memes_images/"
```

and filebrowser uploads files to this directory correctly. But the problem is with image Thumbnail in filebrowser file list. Thumbnails are not shown,
because It tries to show it from link `http://localhost:8000/admin/filebrowser/browse/name.jpg`. The correct link is `http://localhost:8000/static/memes_images/name.jpg`. I try to set it in `settings.py`:

```
site.storage.url = "http://localhost:8000/static/memes_images"
```

but when I set it, FileBrowser uses empty string as image url instead this `http://localhost:8000/static/memes_images/name.jpg`.

How can I change the image url used by FileBrowser?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. But setting MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL helps.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific? Maybe give a reason why this helps, or in what way this helps.